# Can I use WordPress search via the REST API?

Tags: wordpress

WordPress comes out of the box with a search box. Does the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) have a similar search request to search posts? Or is the only option to request posts by field via the [/posts endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/)?

Answer (score 0):

Add the query param `filter[s]={{search terms go here}}`